# Any way to align a few elements to the bottom via CSS in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to do a HTML form that has 3 controls in the same row. All the controls (radio buttons) should be aligned in the same line. Currently, the radio button in the middle column is pushed low because of the long text on top it. I hope the radio buttons in the first and third columns are pushed down in order to align with the radio button in the middle column.

The text in all three columns can be changing. I am not considering any table solution. I am hoping to see a CSS solution because all the controls should be aligned vertically and the extra space between the text and controls in the first and third column should be gone when the form is displayed on smartphones. Here is the code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/78nfp/4/

Here is the html code

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 center">
        <div class="text"> text 1</div>
        <div class="control"><input type="radio" name="test" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 center">
        <div class="text"> text 2 --- blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan blan </div>
        <div class="control"><input type="radio" name="test" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 center">
        <div class="text"> text 3</div>
        <div class="control"><input type="radio" name="test" /></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2ykPN/) that doesn't use a fixed height and doesn't change your current markup.

```
.row {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

We need the radio buttons to later be positioned in relation to the row, so we set it's `position` to `relative`.

```
.row:after {
    clear: both; /*clearfix*/
    display: table;
    content: ' ';
}
```

Apply a clearfix to the row so that it gets the desired height.

```
.col-sm-4 {
    position: static;
}
```

Set the column's `position` to `static` so that the radio buttons aren't positioned relative to it. Then finally...

```
input[type='radio'] {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Position the radio buttons absolutely in relation to their parent with relative positioning (e.g., the row).

For future reference, this may [help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
.text{
    height:200px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/78nfp/6/)

Comment: Try adding some more explanation to your answer to make it more clear

Comment: As said in the post, the text content can change and I cannot set a fixed height to it.